# React Native fetch before render components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, render, use-effect

I am creating a Reat Native app which connects to an API from which it gets data.

I am using React Navigation to handle navigation. The app has a Stack Navigator and a Bottom Tab Navigator. The `StackNavigator` has 4 screens:

- `SignupScreen` which handles creating account;
- `LoginScreen` for handlong log in;
- `SplashScreen` that checks for a local token and logs in the user automatically;
- A `LoadingScreen` that triggers the initial fetch call to the API, stores the response in state and navigates to the `MainFlow` screen;
- A `MainFlow` screen that contains the `TabNavigator`.

The `TabNavigator` has two screens, `FeedScreen`, `Account` and `More` where the initial screen is `FeedScreen`.

The signup/login/local flows are all working fine.

**The issue**: Once the user is logged in successfully the LoadingScreen is triggering the API call but the `MainFlow` components are being rendered before the data is in state. Because the components in `MainFlow` need the data, an error is thrown. How can I render the `FeedScreen` components only once the data is there?

In the `LoadingScreen` I am triggering an API call on `useEffect` from a context object, `QuestionContext`:

```
const LoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { state: authState } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { getQuestionsForUser, getAllQuestions } = useContext(QuestionContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllQuestions();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <YonStatusBar backgroundColor="#310B3B" />
      <Image source={splashLogo} containerStyle={styles.splashLogo} />
      <ActivityIndicator />
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoadingScreen;
```

`getAllQuestions` is a function in `QuestionContext` which makes the API call and navigates to `FeedScreen`:

```
const getAllQuestions = (dispatch) => {
  return async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      const config = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } };
      const response = await yonyonApi.get(`/questions`, config);
      dispatch({ type: 'GET_ALL_QUESTIONS', payload: response.data });
      RootNavigation.navigate('MainFlow');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};
```

`getAllQuestions` is working fine: the API call is successful and I can see that the response is stored in state. However, it navigates to `MainFlow` before that happens.

Finally, this is the `FeedScreen`:

```
const FeedScreen = () => {
  const { state: questionState } = useContext(QuestionContext);

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      {console.log(questionState.questions)}
      <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        <QuestionCard />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default FeedScreen;
```

The `FeedScreen` renders a `QuestionCard` which needs the data in `questionState`. This is what throwing the error: the `QuestionCard` is being rendered before the data is in state.

How can I make the navigation only navigate to `FeedScreen` once the necessary data is in state? Or alternatively, render something else than the `QuestionCard` while the data is not there and once the data is in `questionState` render the `QuestionCard`?

Answer (score 4):

For me i will use screen instead of two screens as follows :

```
 const FeedScreen = () => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { state: authState } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const getAllQuestions = (dispatch) => {
  return async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      const config = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } };
      const response = await yonyonApi.get(`/questions`, config);
      setData(response.data)
      setLoading(false)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllQuestions();
  }, []);

      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          {
            (loading)?
             <ActivityIndicator/>
             :
             <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                <QuestionCard  data={data}/>
              </View>
           }
        </ScrollView>
      );
    };

    export default FeedScreen;
```

Comment: Thank you for your. help. However, this doesn't allow me to use the state variables I have stored in the context. I wouldn't want to create local state in my screen but rather to use the one in the Context. The Context is, at the moment, taking care of all of the async operations such as making the API call. How can I, in the screen, wait for all those operations to be finished and state to be populated, before I render the QuestionCard component? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the initial state of your context to `null` and render your component if it is not `null` ?

```
const [questionState, setQuestionState] = useState(null); 

...

const FeedScreen = () => {
  const { state: questionState } = useContext(QuestionContext);

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      {!!questionState?.questions && console.log(questionState.questions)}
      <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        <QuestionCard />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default FeedScreen;
```